# Having issues loading dataset and phenotype labels file into GSEA

Tags: java, bioinformatics, rna-seq

I formatted the dataset and phenotype labels files according to the instructions but still can't get it to work. This is the error message. Here's an image of the dataset file

[image]

```
---- Full Error Message ----
There were errors: ERROR(S) #:1
Parsing trouble
java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcepti ...

---- Stack Trace ----
# of exceptions: 1
------Unknown file format: /Users/normanfultang/Google Drive (normanfultang@gmail.com)/PostDoc Research/GSEA analyses/gsea.gct no known Parser for ext: ------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown file format: /Users/normanfultang/Google Drive (normanfultang@gmail.com)/PostDoc Research/GSEA analyses/gsea.gct no known Parser for ext: 
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserFactory.read(ParserFactory.java:768)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserFactory.read(ParserFactory.java:725)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserWorker.doInBackground(ParserWorker.java:51)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question, but rather a problem using a tool? Try contacting the author of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the file type is incorrect. In this format, it would need to be saved as a .gct file. Otherwise, you could remove the top two rows and save as a .txt file.

Explanation of accepted file types and formats can be found [here](https://software.broadinstitute.org/cancer/software/gsea/wiki/index.php/Data_formats).